# How to read strings from a text file and use them in grep?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file of strings that I need to search for in another file. So I've tried the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read name; do
   #echo $name
   grep "$name" file.txt > results.txt
done < missing.txt
```

The echo line confirms the file is being read into the variable, but my results file is always empty. Doing the grep command on its own works, I'm obviously missing something very basic here but I have been stuck for a while and can't figure it out.

I've also tried without quotes around the variable. Can someone tell me what I'm missing? Thanks a bunch

Edit - input file was DOS format, set file format to unix and works fine now

Comment: There is also `fgrep` or more recently (the same idea), `grep -F -f listile.txt *.txt` will search all `.txt` files for lines of text ound in `filelist.txt`. Read the `man grep` for the details. If you wnt to search for regex from a file list, it is more complicated. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter oh that is promising! when I try that it only returns the grep result for the last line in the file though (the file with the search strings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess is that you are overwriting your `results.txt` file in every iteration of the while loop (with the single `>`). If it is the case you should at least have the result for the very last line in your `missing.txt` file. Then I think it would suffice to do something like

```sh
#!/bin/bash
 
while read name; do
   #echo "$name"
   grep "$name" file.txt
done < missing.txt > results.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Still no luck though, and putting the output file in that location seems to mess with the variable assignment as well - also I think if I was overwriting it I should at least have the last result from the grep saved to the file, but it is completely blank

Comment: I would try enclosing the while loop in braces. Have you tried grepping the last line by hand to see if it gives some output?

Comment: Yep grepping by hand works, and if I hard code a variable outside the loop and replace the read in variable with the hard coded one it works, so there is some disconnect between the variable I'm reading and using it in grep. But echoing the variable works so I am completely befuddled

Comment: Well, that is a first... I tried to reproduce the issue (in debian buster) but it works fine for me, no problems... I wish I could help any further, good luck!

Comment: Ahhhhh my file was DOS formatted, converted it and it all works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use [grep's `-f` option](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/grep.1.html): Then you only need a single grep call and no loop.

```sh
grep -f missing.txt file.txt > results.txt
```

If the contents of "missing.txt" are fixed strings, not regular expressions, this will speed up the process:

```sh
grep -F -f missing.txt file.txt > results.txt
```

And if you want to find the *words* of missing.txt in the other file, not *partial* words

```sh
grep -F -w -f missing.txt file.txt > results.txt
```

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the information!